# Deadlock while attempting channel concurrency

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm trying to understand the relationship between goroutines, channels, and waitgroups. The below code gives me `all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`. I've tried looking online but really could not understand how it all works.

I'm attempting to have a function take a list of values (a channel with the values, in this example) and do something with them. If an error occurs, do something and put the item in the queue again for it to be tried again soon.

Am I approaching this wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func tester(que chan int, i int) {
    defer wg.Done()

    if i % 7 == 0 {
        fmt.Println("I hate this number!: ", string(i))
        que <- i + 1
    } else {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}

func main() {
    que := make(chan int)

    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        que <- i
        //go get(string(i))
    }

    for elem := range que {
        go tester(que, elem)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(que)
}
```

Comment: This is sort of the opposite of how this type of problem is normally solved, dispatch the workers to receive from the queue. If you want each value handled in it's own goroutine, there's no need for a separate queue in the first place.

Comment: Well I thought of using a queue so that I could send values to be tried again if anything were to go wrong (such as forced example with the number 7)

Answer (score 0):

I've commented on the relevant parts of the code so that's easy to understand.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func tester(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup, queue chan int) {
    // Range over queue until the queue is closed and empty
    for q := range queue {
        if q%7 == 0 {
            fmt.Println("Bad number:", q)
            select {
            // If possible, add it back to the queue as. Used
            // select to drop the number in case the queue is
            // full.
            case queue <- (q + 1):
                fmt.Println("Added back to queue")
            // Drop it
            default:
                fmt.Println("Dropped")
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Println(q)
        }
        select {
        // If the original sender is done sending and queue
        // is also empty i.e., no backlog; then close the queue
        // so that for with range clause could stop.
        case <-ctx.Done():
            if len(queue) == 0 {
                close(queue)
            }
        default:
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    // Queue of size 10
    queue := make(chan int, 10)

    // Context
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    // Use WaitGroup for the tester (worker goroutine)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)

    // Worker goroutine
    go tester(ctx, &wg, queue)

    // Try for 0 to 30
    for num := 0; num <= 30; num++ {
        queue <- num
    }

    // Cancel the context to signal the original sender
    // is done sending
    cancel()

    // Wait for tester (worker goroutine) to complete
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Sample output:

```
Bad number: 0
Dropped
1
2
3
4
5
6
Bad number: 7
Added back to queue
8
9
10
11
8
12
13
Bad number: 14
Added back to queue
15
16
17
18
19
20
Bad number: 21
Added back to queue
22
23
15
24
25
26
27
Bad number: 28
Added back to queue
22
29
30
29
```

--

Edit: One producer, Multiple consumers

In the following example, there's one producer and multiple consumers. I've used a ticker to check the queue is empty after every specified interval. If the queue is empty, signalling all consumers to stop by closing the queue after clearing their respective backlog.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func consumer(wg *sync.WaitGroup, queue chan int) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for n := range queue {
        switch n % 7 {
        // add back to queue, if possible
        case 0:
            select {
            case queue <- (n + 1):
                fmt.Printf("Back to queue: %d -> %d\n", n, n+1)
            default:
                fmt.Println("- Drop:", n)
            }
        // process
        default:
            fmt.Println("+ Done:", n)
        }
    }
}

func producer(wg *sync.WaitGroup, queue chan int) {
    defer wg.Done()

    for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
        queue <- i // send to the queue
    }

    d := time.Duration(5 * time.Second) // duration
    tick := time.NewTicker(d)           // ticker with duration 'd'

    // Checks every duration 'd' if the queue is empty, and
    // if empty, close the queue.
    for range tick.C {
        if len(queue) == 0 {
            close(queue) // close the queue to signal consumers to stop
            break
        }
    }
    tick.Stop() // stop the ticker now
}

func main() {
    var (
        wg      = &sync.WaitGroup{}
        nWorker = 5                    // num of worker goroutines
        maxQ    = 5                    // max queue size
        queue   = make(chan int, maxQ) // queue
    )

    for i := 0; i < nWorker; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go consumer(wg, queue)
    }

    wg.Add(1)
    go producer(wg, queue)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Sample output:

```
+ Done: 4
+ Done: 5
+ Done: 6
Back to queue: 7 -> 8
+ Done: 8
+ Done: 9
+ Done: 10
+ Done: 8
+ Done: 3
+ Done: 12
+ Done: 2
- Drop: 14
+ Done: 15
+ Done: 16
+ Done: 17
+ Done: 18
+ Done: 19
+ Done: 20
+ Done: 13
+ Done: 22
+ Done: 23
+ Done: 1
+ Done: 25
+ Done: 24
+ Done: 26
+ Done: 27
Back to queue: 28 -> 29
+ Done: 29
+ Done: 29
- Drop: 0
Back to queue: 21 -> 22
+ Done: 11
+ Done: 22
```

Comment: Thank you for this, you were more than clear. Is there any way to implement more goroutines on this? I thought of using the channel as a way to have an active pool of items from which a number of goroutines take, and being able to put items back in as to retry if anything were to go wrong ( as you handled in your example )

Comment: Yes, it is possible. One Producer, Multiple Consumers. So, launch X number of worker goroutines but be careful of a few things: closing a closed channel panics, try to do it from the producer side and a few things. Give it a try and if you can't we'd discuss further.

Comment: @etha.1 I've added a new example

Comment: The One producer, Multiple consumers program can panic because the program does not ensure that all sends to `queue` happen before `close(queue)`.  I inserted a sleep in the program at https://play.golang.org/p/p8HT1IRINbg to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Ah, right. Sending after closing the channel would result in panic. @CeriseLimón Do you have a better pattern in mind? Closing the queue channel for this problem is tricky; it'd be great if you can suggest something.